# UIViewController.dismiss() not calling presentingViewController.dismiss()

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit

[apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss) on UIViewController dismiss(animated:completion:) says that

> The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view
>   controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view
>   controller itself, UIKit asks the presenting view controller to handle
>   the dismissal.

but when I override the presenting controller's dismiss

```
override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)
```

it is not called

ViewController1 -> present ViewController2

ViewController2.dismiss -> dismiss from ViewController2 is called and ViewController1.(override)dismiss is not called

Comment: Did you manage to get override dismiss to fire in VC1? I'm facing the same issue. Any insight would help ;)

Comment: nope, I just used ViewController2.presentingViewController.dismiss

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of [present(_:animated:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present):

> The object on which you call this method may not always be the one
>   that handles the presentation. Each presentation style has different
>   rules governing its behavior. For example, a full-screen presentation
>   must be made by a view controller that itself covers the entire
>   screen. If the current view controller is unable to fulfill a request,
>   it forwards the request up the view controller hierarchy to its
>   nearest parent, which can then handle or forward the request.

In case of iPhone (*horizontally compact environment*) it uses FullScreen mode by default. So here `ViewController1` may not be the 'presentingViewController'.

Comment: if i do ViewController2.presentingViewController.dismiss it does work

Answer (score 0):

**[Spoiler - Work-around]**

I had a similar issue with a modal vc and ended up working things out differently.

My modal style was initially:

```
 modalVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
```

and changing that to

```
modalVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

triggers the life cycle calls to fire on the presentingVC when I dismiss the modal so that did the trick for me. I can now make sure code runs whenever the modal gets dismissed without having to bother with delegation etc...

I hope that can help someone too in the future.